# mimic a domain on localhost

Tags: domain-name

I wish to know how can I host some domain names on my own machine.

I've installed wamp, but I don't wana use localhost/folder_name to access the project's I'm working on. I know that is possible to type www.myproject.com into my browser, but i don't know how or what to search on google. All I've tried didn't give me anything useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hosts` file controls access to this.  In Windows XP, it's `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\Hosts` with no file extension.  You'll need to use notepad to edit the file and add a line reading

```
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

If there is already a line starting 127.0.0.1 then you should add www.example.com to the end of it

```
127.0.0.1 localhost www.example.com
```

Keep in mind that while this line is there you will never be able to access www.example.com on the real server.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your etc/hosts file and add reference to www.myproject.com pointing to 127.0.0.1